# Php script not processing data that it is receiving from android

Tags: java, php, android, json

I'm trying to pass parameters to my php script. The data gets passed but always returns "success" as 0. I tested the php by echoing the query after passing values, it works fine and puts all the data. Even `var_dump($_POST)` indicates it receives data but it always returns "success" as 0.

**Adding parameters:**

```
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("states", states));
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("min_budget", min_budget));
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("max_budget", max_budget));
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("activity", activity));
Log.d("Passing parameters: ", params.toString());

// Check your log cat for JSON response
try {
    JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_resorts, "POST", params);
```

**`makeHttpRequest` method:**

```
DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params, HTTP.UTF_8));
Log.d("Passing parameters 2: ", params.toString());

HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
Log.d("Entity 2: ", httpEntity.toString());
is = httpEntity.getContent();`
```

**logcat:**

```
Log.d("Passing parameters 2: ", params.toString());
Passing parameters 2:: [states=Himachal Pradesh, min_budget=1,000, max_budget=9,000, activity=Leopard Safari]
```

**recieved by android:**

```
Data received:: array(4) {
    ["states"]=>
    string(16) "Himachal Pradesh"
    ["min_budget"]=>
    string(5) "1,000"
    ["max_budget"]=>
    string(5) "9,000"
    ["activity"]=>
    string(14) "Leopard Safari"
}

{"success":0,"message":"No resort found"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this beginning in your php, for my app it did work:

```
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'])) {
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: {$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']}");
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
        header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 86400');    // cache for 1 day
        }

    // Access-Control headers are received during OPTIONS requests
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'OPTIONS') {

        if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_METHOD']))
            header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS");         

        if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']))
            header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers:  {$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']}");

        exit(0);
    }

    $postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
    if (isset($postdata)) {

        $request = json_decode($postdata);
        $username = "";
        $password = "";
    //here use your values
    if (!empty($request->password)) {
             $password = $request->password;
            }
            if (!empty($request->username)) {
            $username = $request->username;
            }
(...)
```

just make sure you are pointing correctly in the httpPost to the php file